# How to add additional method to pymongo Collection, Cursor objects?

Tags: python-3.x, class, pymongo, metaprogramming

Hello I have a small problem and I am not sure how to solve it:

Well, I am working with the pymongo library and I want to do something like this so that the Collection, Cursor or CommandCursor object gets an additional method to export data. So far I have come up with two ways how I can add this, but they seem to be ugly ways.

The first is to dynamically inject export functions into instances of these objects, e.g:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.collection import Collection

def export(*args, **kwargs):
    print("do something")

client = MongoClient(host=host, port=port, connect=False)
db = client.get_database("some_database")
collection = db.get_collection("some_collection")
cursor = db["some_collection"].find({})

# first idea:
setattr(collection, export.__name__, export) 
setattr(cursor, export.__name__, export)

# second idea:

class ExporableCollection:
     def __init__(self, collection):
         self.collection = collection

     def export(self, *args, **kwargs): pass


exportable_coll = ExporableCollection(collection)

# but the problem here is if I want to do e.g
exportable_coll.find({}) # -> it won't work, I need to do this like:
exportable_coll.collection.find({})
```

Is there any smart way how I can add additional method to these classes ?
Or maybe is there a way that I can create another class from Collection object which will have the same methods, attributes but with my additional export method (maybe some way with metaprogramming?)

Is there a way how to make this kind of behavior ?

```py
class ExporableCollection:
     def __init__(self, collection):
         self = collection  # this probably won't work

     def export(self, *args, **kwargs): pass


exportable_coll = ExporableCollection(collection)
exportable_coll.find({})
```